# magento import category_ids is empty

Tags: .net, magento, soap

With .NET I create a new Product with SOAP V2. All fields are correctly inserted, without the CATEGORY. Category is always empty ! (I Have a Category with the ID 37)

```
    Dim para As New SOAP2.catalogProductCreateEntity

    Dim ar(0) As String
    ar(0) = "37"

    para.category_ids = ar
    para.name = strRefmatID
...
    rc = gService.catalogProductCreate(gSession, "simple", "64", strRefmatID, para, "0")
```

What is wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try category_id  or entity_id, not category_ids. Look in the table structure to see where is the problem .